# Elasticsearch Geospatial giving me exaggerated distance measurements

Tags: elasticsearch

Problem:

I am using Elasticsearch to index some listings on my site and I keep getting ridiculously exaggerated distances. Even when I search using the same coordinates my document has I still get distances upward of 3000km.

Post:

```
    [{
        "expiryDate": "2014-04-11 02:32:16",
        "geo": {
          "lon": 45.297,
          "lat": 75.0755
        },
        "id": "5571afb7ae2c287f4d54b713",
        "images": [],
        "imagesLinks": [],

    }]
```

Mapping:

```
   {
    "listingsell" : {
        "properties" : {
            "geo" : {
              "type" : "geo_point",
              "fielddata" : {
                    "format" : "compressed",
                    "precision" : "1m"
                }  
             }
        } 
    }
}
```

Query:

```
       {

    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "90000mi",
                    "geo" : {
                        "lat" : 45.1339,
                        "lon" : 75.019
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "geo" : {
                    "lat" : 45.1339,
                    "lon" : 75.019
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "mi"
          }
      }
  ],
}
```

Result :

```
  {
"sort":[2247.4929]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `geo_point` indexed in a wrong way:

```
       "geo": {
          "lon": 45.297,
          "lat": 75.0755
        }
```

or the sorting is done in a wrong way:

```
              "geo" : {
                    "lat" : 45.1339,
                    "lon" : 75.019
              }
```

Meaning you mixed up `lat` with `lon`.